# Very strange behaviour of checkboxes in Chrome & Opera with jQuery Waypoints

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

In summary: I used the jQuery Waypoints to give an element fixed position.
My HTML markup matches the one used at the Waypoints developer, so does the CSS. So the code works perfectly. It does exactly what I need (give an element `position: fixed` after reaching a particular point).

The point is that when you try to check a box in the element that has a fixed position, it is not marked as checked right after the click, but only after you scroll a page.
**The same behaviour affects not only checkboxes, but also textfields.**

Here's a test website http://dstest.atservers.net/katalog

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. Scroll the page to the middle
2. Check any box or textfield in the left module.
3. Its marked as activated only when you scroll a page again.

In **Firefox** (Stable, Nightly releases) the elements are activated right when you click it.
In **Opera, Chrome** (on 1 PC and 3 laptops I checked it on) they are not.

All the browsers are of the latest versions.

Any help is appreciated a lot.

**Update:**

Also works fine in IE9+

**Fixed the errors in the console, still the same bug.**

**FIXED NOW:**

It has been a problem with rendering.
This is what fixed the issue, in case someone encounters it further.

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Comment: you have called `$.waypoints` method but there is no such method in `waypoints-sticky.js`, i think there is problem in ``waypoints-sticky.js`

Comment: If the problem is in the JS, who does it works fine in FF and IE9+?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a really similar issue, without using Waypoints.

I have a cross-domain iframe using jQuery and postMessage. Everything works perfectly in Firefox. In Chrome, if you scroll the page at all, the first mousedown on any checkbox will cause the page to scroll up to the top of the iframe. If you scroll down again and click the same checkbox, it works as expected.

The CSS patch above has no effect.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?